# How to add all the count value in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
[
  {
    _id: '101',
    count: 5,
    city: 'Bangalore'
  },
  {
    _id: '102',
    count: 4,
    city: 'Mumbai'
  }
]
```

How can I add all the count values in mongodb using mongoose with selected city and without any city provided ?

Comment: DO you want to get the sum of all the count from the collection? Ex:  4+5 = 9, Total Count = 9?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But also if I mention any particular city, it should sum the count of only those cities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation framework to achieve it, this will add all the count from the collection.

```
db.aggregateSumDemo.aggregate([{
    $group: {
      _id: null,
       "TotalCount": {
          $sum: "$count"
        }
     }
 } ] );
```

When you pass specific condition, it will only count values based on id.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: 'Pass id here',
        count: { $sum: '$count' }
    }
 }, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        count: '$count'
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this solution work?